# Continued problems with 16.04.1 with Dropbox and Nautilus

Tags: unity, 16.04, nautilus, dropbox, synaptic

I got notifications saying to re-start Nautilus and so on for Dropbox to work, and of course lots of problems opening windows, tabs closing when they should come to the front, etc.

My solution was to remove Dropbox from the Start Up menu. But I still want to use it, of course.

My instruction from @heynnema for a solution was:

> Using Synaptic, enter dropbox into the search area, and you should see
>   dropbox, and nautilus-dropbox. Right-click on nautilus-dropbox and
>   select Mark for complete removal. Left-click on dropbox and select
>   Mark for installation.
>
> Then go back to the search box and enter g15daemon, right-click and
>   select Mark for re-installation.
>
> Then click the APPLY icon. After it's done, exit Synaptic. Dropbox may
>   ask you to restart Nautilus by clicking the OK button. Confirm that
>   dropbox is working normally, as expected. See if your problem with
>   Chrome/etc is resolved.

I opened Synaptic, but "normal" dropbox is not present, only php-dropbox, caja dropbox, thunar-dropbox-plugin, libnet-dropbox-api-per... and nautilus-dropbox, which I was able to remove.

(There are two other things installed: libg15render1 and libg15-1, both current versions.)

I searched for g15... and tried to re-install g15daemon and got the following message:

> E: Internal Error, No file name for g15daemon:amd64

Then I tried remove it, and re-install and this did not work.

Then I removed it completely, and re-installed, which seemed to work, though I got a "package failure" notice and the message:

> E: g15daemon: subprocess installed post-installation script returned
>   error exit status 1

Finally, I closed Synaptic and opened Ubuntu Software, and tried to find Dropbox, but it was indicated that Nautilus-Dropbox was still installed. It could not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

When you viewed nautilus-dropbox in Synaptic, and marked it for complete removal, did you remember to click on the APPLY icon?

If you don't see dropbox in Synaptic, you can download it directly at:

https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/ubuntu/dropbox_2015.10.28_amd64.deb

g15daemon is only required if you have a Logitech G15 keyboard. If you don't have such a keyboard, you can safely uninstall this.

Comment: I  am sorry I wasn't clear but I WAS able to completely remove nautilus-dropbox. Your instructions were very clear. Thanks for additional into/steps.

Comment: Did you successfully install Dropbox from the .deb file? Do you have a g15 keyboard? Are the problems solved completely? Cheers, Al